# android code to find country from ip address of user

Tags: android, ip, country, country-codes

I want to filter nearby deals of users.

I can able to get the ip address of the user device and store in mysql database. but i couldn't able to get the country name.

how to find country using user device ip address?

Comment: Info here: http://www.iplocation.net/

Comment: thanks. how to use that with android? any sample codes?

Comment: I would use a PHP side thing with a HTTP request to do what you want